# Telerik grid, razor and VB.NET in Ajax binding mode

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, telerik

I'm trying to create a Grid in MVC3 with razor and VB.NET. The normal Grid works fine, sorts and paginates fine, but when trying to make the Ajax binding, I get an error 500 - internal server error when I try to go to the next page.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my controller:

```
Function Index() As ViewResult
    Return View(Me.orgRepository.GetOrgs())   
End Function

<GridAction()> 
Function AjaxGrid() As ActionResult 
    Return View(New GridModel(Of hdmtORG)() With 
        {
            .Data = Me.orgRepository.GetOrgs()
        })
End Function
```

And this is my view

```
@Code
'declare the grid and enable features   
Dim grid = Html.Telerik().Grid(Model) _
    .Name("Grid") _  
    .Pageable() _
    .Sortable() _   
    .Filterable() _
    .DataBinding(Function(dataBinding) dataBinding.Ajax.Select("AjaxGrid", "Org"))   
    'Add grid columns
    grid.Columns(Function(columns) columns.Bound(Function(o) o.orgNAME).Width(200))   
    grid.Columns(Function(columns) columns.Bound(Function(o) o.orgIMAGE).Width(200))
    grid.Columns(Function(columns) columns.Bound(Function(o) o.orgUNIT).Width(200))

    'Render the grid   
    grid.Render()
End code
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't program in vb, but shouldn't the controller function look more like this:

```
<GridAction()> 
Function AjaxGrid() As ActionResult 
    Return View(New GridModel(Of hdmtORG)() From 
        {
            Data = Me.orgRepository.GetOrgs()
        })
End Function
```

Comment: @Scheveningen, sorry the code I put doesn't work. Isn't With .Data used for single properties, while what you need to return is an IEnumerable? In c# it would be return View(new GridModel<hdmtORG>
            {
                Data = orgRepository.GetOrgs()
            });

Comment: Thanks Daniel, my code is ok. I found the problem! It was a circular reference and I figured out how to fix it, thanks! Using my same code (or yours in c#), do you know how can I select some fields (for example just orgName and orgDate) instead of return all the data (orgId, orgName, ....)

Comment: Glad your code is working. -- var results = (from o in orgRepositry.GetOrgs() select new { o.orgName, o.orgDate });